# Magento 2 Display 3 items per row in products/category pages?

Tags: magento2

How to display 3 items per row on products/category pages for 2 column Magento 2?

Comment: Hi @SagarDobariya were you able to solve your issue?

Answer (score 6):

Create or modify style in `_listings.less` in `Magento_Catalog\web\css\source\module` path

```
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__l) {
  .products-grid {
      .product-item {
          width: 100%/5;
      }
   }
}
```

to

```
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__l) {
    .page-products.page-layout-2columns-left,
    .page-products.page-layout-2columns-right {
        .products-grid .product-item {
            width: 100%/3;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i try but this is not working for 2 column left i have also try .page-products.page-layout-1column {
        .products-grid {
            .product-item {
                width: 100%/3;
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Try this `.page-products.page-layout-2columns-left .products-grid {
        .product-item {
            width: 100%/3;
        }
    }`

Comment: Try above updated code, this will work.

Comment: What if I only want this in search results? 
Could anyone please help me with this.

Comment: Above code will work on default Magento setup as well, But if you have change layout from 2columns to 1column or 3columns in this case you have to add this selector `.page-products.page-layout-1column` or `.page-products.page-layout-3columns` respected.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by copying the file

```
vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/module-catalog/web/css/source/module/_listings.less
```

to my theme at `THEME/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/module/_listing.less` and adding my code under the `media-width` mixin:

```
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__l) {

    ...
    
    //
    // Change Products per row from 5 to 3 in custom page layout
    // ---------------------------------------------------------
    .page-products.page-layout-2columns-left {
        .products-grid {
            .product-item {
                margin-left: 2%;
                padding: 5px;
                width: calc(~'(100% - 6%)/3');
            }
        }
    }
```